# Using the WHQL Powershell API, how would I add a Filter.Driver.FileSystem to my features targets?

Tags: powershell, driver, digital-signature

I have a driver to test, and in the HLK UI I would under Selection->Software Device->select the machine pool->search for driver and check it.  Then I would right-click driver and 'Add/Modify Features' and add Filter.Driver.FileSystem ( it already has Filter.Driver.DeviceGuard/Fundamentals/Security selected by default).  I am trying to replicate this using the API and Powershell.

If I have a product instance $productInstance, I can get all targets from the product instance.  From that I can get the current features using GetFeatures().  This shows the existing ones (DeviceGuard, Fundamentals, Security).  But how do I 'add' a new one.  Looking at the documentation for Target class it has an AddFeature() which is used to 'add a feature'. it takes a 'Feature'.    However I can't see how to create a new feature object of type Filter.Driver.FileSystem to add?

```
         Write-Host "Try adding feature to target"   #  Need to a Filter.Driver.FileSystem somehow
         $targets = $productInstance.GetTargets() | Where  {$_.Name -eq $deviceTarget.Name}.
         foreach ($t in $targets) {  
             # t = <my driver> 
             # family =  Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection.DbConnectionTargetFamily
             # Type = Filter
             Write-Host "  t = " $t.Name " Family: " $t.TargetFamily " type: " $t.TargetType

             $featuresInTarget = $t.GetFeatures(). # contains 3 expected features
             Write-Host "feature[0] type =" $featuresInTarget[0].TargetType. # Filter
             Write-Host "feature[0] = " $featuresInTarget[0].Name            # DeviceGuard

             # add Feature   Filter.Driver.FileSystem 
             $newFeature =  New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Feature -ArgumentList Driver.FileSystem
             $t.AddFeature($newFeature)
```

The last 2 statements do not work but what I am trying to do.  The new Feature line responds with an exception. (exception:  A constr
uctor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.Feature. )

Also I am doing  $ObjectModel  = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($env:WTTSTDIO + "microsoft.windows.Kits.Hardware.objectmodel.dll")
earlier in the code and am able to do things like

```
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.ProductInstance]$productInstance = $null,
        [Parameter()]
        [String]$driversToTest = $null
    )
```

So the object model should be loaded.   I don't deem to be able to find an enumeration of the Filter types or how to create a new one of a specific type to add to my target

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you very much

Rich Parker

Comment: The [`Feature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/api/feature-class) class has no public constructors, and seemingly neither do the other classes in the [`Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/api/microsoftwindowskitshardwareobjectmodel) namespace - I personally don't know how instances can be created / obtained.